# How to plot time in YYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS on y axis in python

Tags: python

I have dates in a CSV file spanning 6hours in the format 1/1/2020 0:00:00. I need to plot this on the y axis to correlate with the other data.
Since they are all on the same day, i only want to plot the time, with a 1 second interval for 30mins on an inverted y axis

This is my code only for that part, obviously the limits (2019, 2020) is wrong, i have been playing around with it o see how it plots. I'm using matplotlib.
Please help

```
#set up common elements between the subplots
for i, ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
    ax1.set_ylim(2019, 2020)
    ax.invert_yaxis()
```

The final outcome is to plot an oilfield well log from a CSV file
Below is what i have done so far

```
1.    
    import pandas as pd
    import lasio
    import plotly.express as px
    from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from datetime import datetime
    import matplotlib.pyplot
    import matplotlib.dates
    import datetime
    import matplotlib.dates as mdates
    from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
    from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
    register_matplotlib_converters()



2.   
 df = pd.read_csv('EDR_data.csv', sep=',', header=0)
    df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
    # extract dt.time
    df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.time
    
    # set the dt.times to today's date
    df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'].apply(str))
    
    # Format Date Time

3.
# ploting curves

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,20))
curve_names = ['Hole Depth (feet)', 'Weight on Bit (klbs)', 'Rate Of Penetration (ft_per_hr)', 'Total Pump Output (gal_per_min)', 'Standpipe Pressure (psi)', 'Differential Pressure (psi', 'Flow (flow_percent)', 'Rotary RPM (RPM)', 'Hook Load (klbs)', 'Block Height (feet)', 'Bit Depth (feet)']

#set up plot axes
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,4), (0,0), rowspan=1, colspan=1)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((1,4), (0,1), rowspan=1, colspan=1)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((1,4), (0,2), rowspan=1, colspan=1)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((1,4), (0,3), rowspan=1, colspan=1)

# axis 4 twins
ax5 = ax4.twiny()
ax6 = ax4.twiny()
ax7 = ax4.twiny()

#axis 3 twins
ax8 = ax3.twiny()

# axis 2 twins
ax9 = ax2.twiny()
ax10 = ax2.twiny()

# axis 1 twin 
ax11 = ax1.twiny()


# main axis plots
ax1.plot("Hole Depth (feet)", "Time", data=df, color= "red", lw=0.5)
ax1.set_xlim(2500, 3300)
ax1.xaxis.label.set_color("red")
ax1.title.set_color('red')
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', colors="red")
ax2.plot("Weight on Bit (klbs)", "Time", data=df, color= "red", lw=0.5)
ax2.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax2.xaxis.label.set_color("red")
ax2.title.set_color('red')
ax2.tick_params(axis='x', colors="red")
ax3.plot("Rate Of Penetration (ft_per_hr)", "Time", data=df, color= "red", lw=0.5)
ax3.set_xlim(0, 350)
ax3.xaxis.label.set_color("red")
ax3.title.set_color('red')
ax3.tick_params(axis='x', colors="red")
ax4.plot("Total Pump Output (gal_per_min)", "Time", data=df, color= "red", lw=0.5)
ax4.set_xlim(0, 1000)
ax4.xaxis.label.set_color("red")
ax4.title.set_color('red')
ax4.tick_params(axis='x', colors="red")



# axis 4 twin plots
ax5.plot("Standpipe Pressure (psi)", "Time", data=df, color= "blue", lw=0.5)
ax5.set_xlim(0, 4000)
ax5.spines["top"].set_position(("axes", 1.04))
ax5.spines["top"].set_visible(True)
ax5.xaxis.label.set_color("blue")
ax5.title.set_color('blue')
ax5.tick_params(axis='x', colors="blue")

ax6.plot("Differential Pressure (psi)", "Time", data=df, color= "green", lw=0.5)
ax6.set_xlim(-3000, 1000)
ax6.spines["top"].set_position(("axes", 1.08))
ax6.spines["top"].set_visible(True)
ax6.xaxis.label.set_color("green")
ax6.title.set_color('green')
ax6.tick_params(axis='x', colors="green")

ax7.plot("Flow (flow_percent)", "Time", data=df, color= "purple", lw=0.5)
ax7.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax7.spines["top"].set_position(("axes", 1.12))
ax7.spines["top"].set_visible(True)
ax7.xaxis.label.set_color("purple")
ax7.title.set_color('purple')
ax7.tick_params(axis='x', colors="purple")


# axis 3 twin plots
ax8.plot("Rotary RPM (RPM)", "Time", data=df, color= "blue", lw=0.5)
ax8.set_xlim(0, 80)
ax8.spines["top"].set_position(("axes", 1.04))
ax8.spines["top"].set_visible(True)
ax8.xaxis.label.set_color("blue")
ax8.title.set_color('blue')
ax8.tick_params(axis='x', colors="blue")

# axis 2 twin plots
ax9.plot("Hook Load (klbs)", "Time", data=df, color= "blue", lw=0.5)
ax9.set_xlim(0, 150)
ax9.spines["top"].set_position(("axes", 1.04))
ax9.spines["top"].set_visible(True)
ax9.xaxis.label.set_color("blue")
ax9.title.set_color('blue')
ax9.tick_params(axis='x', colors="blue")


ax10.plot("Block Height (feet)", "Time", data=df, color= "green", lw=0.5)
ax10.set_xlim(0, 150)
ax10.spines["top"].set_position(("axes", 1.08))
ax10.spines["top"].set_visible(True)
ax10.xaxis.label.set_color("green")
ax10.title.set_color('green')
ax10.tick_params(axis='x', colors="green")

# axis 1 twin plot
ax11.plot("Bit Depth (feet)", "Time", data=df, color= "blue", lw=0.5)
ax11.set_xlim(2500, 3300)
ax11.spines["top"].set_position(("axes", 1.04))
ax11.spines["top"].set_visible(True)
ax11.xaxis.label.set_color("blue")
ax11.title.set_color('blue')
ax11.tick_params(axis='x', colors="blue")

# format y-axis label to hh:mm:ss
formatter_yx1 = matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda s, x: time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(s)))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter_yx1)

#set up common elements between the subplots
for i, ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
    ax1.set_ylim(2019, 2020)
    ax.invert_yaxis() 
   
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position("top")
    ax.xaxis.set_label_position("top")
    ax.set_xlabel(curve_names[i])
    
    if i == 3:
        ax.spines["top"].set_position(("axes", 1))
    else:
        ax.grid()
    
# hide  tick labw=els on y-axis
for ax in [ax2, ax3, ax4]:
    plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
    
# reduce the space between each subplot
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0.05)
    df['Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Time'],format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time


# Set-up to have matplotlib use its support for notebook inline plots
%matplotlib inline

df.head(1801)
```

Comment: you need to firstly specify which library you are using for the plotting (looks like matplotlib? I am not 100% sure)

Comment: Yes @Alex Kong That's what I'm using, matplotlib

Comment: oh I just notice that you want to format the values on **y** axis which I am not quite familiar with--usually people ask about formatting values on **x** axis lol

Comment: Please provide a sample of the type of data you're using and example code that shows the problem you have - with that, people will be able to provide suggestions on how to change the representation of the time on the y-axis.

Comment: By the way, 6 hours is 21,600 seconds, are you sure you want 1 second intervals? What resolution are you viewing / printing that at?

Comment: @Grismar, I am plotting oilfield logs and need the 1 second for the first 30 minutes.  I will later work around it to plot with a bigger step interval to visualize  for the whole 6 hours